# admob network Integration in android

Tags: android, admob, mobfox

Currently have Admob with 9k impressions and 0.06$ ecpm so i  want to use MobFox as backup . so I registered  an account with MobFox and setup mediation with Admob with MobFox publisher ID. Do I need to install any SDK updates in my App and re-release it or just Admob sdk ? i get 0 requests in MobFox so whats the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Check LogCat for the error reason. Most likely, it's because you need to include the MobFox [SDK and adapter](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/ad-network-mediation) libraries in your project.

Comment: i added them and still and nothing on my mobfox dashboard

Comment: Do you know how to check the Android logs (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html)? What is the error when you make a request?

Comment: oky i downloaded GoogleAdMobAdapter_MobFoxSDK_Android_4.1.3.jar file and added it to my project lib with Admob sdk and i got ads from ADmob only when i tried to remove admob sdk GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.3.1 i couldn

Comment: couldn't add this line adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

Comment: You'll need to have The Google AdMob SDK jar and the GoogleAdMobAdapter_MobFoxSDK_Android_4.1.3.jar included in your project. The first jar gets you AdMob integration, with the capability to do mediation. The second jar gets you MobFox integration with mediation.

Comment: oky i did that exactly but on mobfox i get No Ad Requests and on admob i receive ads so i just made Manifest instructions and put the 2 jars and ad code in my activity ~ AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
~  i'm missing something else?